# Exporting results from get-acl to a .csv

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am trying to get the following powershell script to output the results into a .csv.  The .csv file is created but there is no data, what am I doing wrong?

```
$rootfolder = Get-ChildItem -recurse -Path [PATH] | where {$_.Attributes -eq 'Directory'} 
foreach ($userdir in $rootfolder) { 
$userdir.FullName 
get-acl $userdir.FullName | foreach {write-host "The owner is : " $_.Owner -Foregroundcolor Green } | export-csv c:\powershell\test.csv
Write-Host "`n" 
}
```

Comment: You're attempting to write to the same file inside a loop, without appending. That's probably not the only thing that's wrong, but it's certainly not helping you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send the output of a `foreach` further in the pipeline in the way you're attempting; you need to export each item individually. Revised script (note that I've also amended your `where-object` to test the `PSIsContainer` property of each item returned by `gci`):

```
$rootfolder = Get-ChildItem -recurse -Path [path] | where {$_.PSIsContainer} 
foreach ($userdir in $rootfolder) { 
get-acl -path $userdir.FullName | export-csv c:\powershell\test.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

However, I think you'll be disappointed with the results. `get-acl` produces a collection of objects, not a collection of basic strings. For example, if I run `get-acl` on my profile directory, I get this:

```
PS C:\Users\ME> get-acl .|select-object access|fl *


Access : {System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule,
         System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule}
```

Running the above script, all I see in the `Access` column of the CSV is `System.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationRuleCollection` - because that's what's produced, a collection. To get the *full* ACL, you will need to do additional processing to pull out each element of that collection. Repeat for the other fields that also return collections.